# Excel - Transfer inputs from one sheet to another sheet to do calculations and returns a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I'm just wondering if I could link the two sheets in Excel where you can transfer inputs from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 to do some calculations and then return a value back to Sheet 1.

See the attached Example

[image]

C4 and C5 from Sheet 2 are sent to Sheet1 C4 and C5 to calculate C9 in Sheet 1 and then return this value to C6 in Sheet 2

D4 and D5 from Sheet 2 are sent to Sheet 1 C4 and C5 to calculate C9 in Sheet 1 and then return this value to D6 in Sheet 2

Comment: the way you describe it, you'll need VBA. But you should be able to put the formula you are using in Sheet1C9 into sheet2C6, then modify that formula using appropriate anchoring to copy across to D6 etc.

Comment: How can I know the Avg lifetime value is calculated?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must have programming in your background:  the way you speak of the problem implies it.

Excel takes a different way of thinking. Instead of looking at it as "take this and do that to it then present it here" you go the other way:  "HERE is where the result goes and hidden in the cell behind that display is a formula that LOOKS to different places, finds what it needs, and operates on that to result in this displayed result."

Believe it or not, that is a huge difference. As described, `gns100` is dead on:  you must use VBA to program a solution. Because Excel flat out does not do what you want; in particular, it will NOT move something from one place to another, not ever.

But there is wonderfully good news. You clearly have a formula whose performance you are happy with in Sheet1!C9 as the only steps you describe needing are those of moving of information into place for that formula to work and then moving its result back to Sheet2!C6 for presentation or some other further on thing. And then to realize it needs to do the next data ending up in D6, then another set in E6, and so on.

The answer then, is to forget all about moving information into place. Simply place the formula that is in Sheet1!C9 into Sheet2!D6. Do this by pressing F2 and copying the entire contents of the formula editor's display, pressing Escape, going to Sheet2!D6, and finally pressing F2 to open the formula editor for that cell and pasting into it.

At this point, the formula will not give exactly the result you still see in Sheet1!C9. You want to then copy the CELL and paste it to the other cells you need a result in:  D6, E6, and so on. But copy the cell, not the formula in the cell only the way you did in the paragraph above. This way the formula will change to use Sheet2!D4:D5, not C4:C5, and that is of obvious importance.

However, while you want that change to occur (so cells referred to on THIS page), you do not want it to change cell references for cells it refers to on the OTHER page. Those must stay the same as you copy from C6 to D6, E6, and so on. So you need to make their references "absolute" which is done by placing a `$` before the column letter and the row number. Sounds obnoxious, but you only have to do it this one time. So enter the formula editor and make the edit "by hand" moving to each place and typing the `$`, or use your mouse to highlight each reference (the whole reference) and pressing `F4`. You'll see that add the `$`'s. Press Enter to save the work and exit the formula editor. Once this is done, you can copy the cell itself over to however many row 6 cells you need it in and it will work just as if it were still on Sheet1.

In other words, there is no need to do the work on Sheet1 and then transfer the result to Sheet2. Just leave Sheet1 as is, and let Sheet2 look to the same table of data its formula does but since it is a cell on Sheet2 that is looking, the result will be on Sheet2, exactly where you tell it to be. And the several/many further results are just in different cells (D6, E6, ...) and happen in parallel instead of being done one step after another like in programming.

Nothing ever gets moved to make this physically happen. So no programming needed as Excel takes your request for results and performs the programmatic steps on its own in the background. It's still "programming" but you interface with it like you are the "customer/end user" not like you are the programmer. (And instead of you being frustrated with the client's demands and fantasies, Excel is frustrated with you!) This is the huge difference between Excel's process model and that of programming.